# How to pass longitude and latitude within typeahead script

Tags: javascript, ajax, geolocation

I have a value created in a type-ahead script that works fine until I try to pass geo-coords along with my typeahead item.  if I hard code the geo variables it works fine.  I have broken down the two VAR examples below on what works and what does not.  Any ideas? please help and thanks

```
function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

    document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("lon").value = position.coords.longitude;
```

if I hard code a value like the two lines of code below below everything works great. Just testing values

```
var lat = 123.123444;
var lon = 100.999999;
```

But if I do the next two lines, my typeahead script will display dropdown result, but will not let me select a result

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;


}




$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_input').typeahead({

        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_script.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item;

                    }));
                }

            })
        },
        updater: function(item) {
            location.href = 'cart.php?shop_name=' + item + '&latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + lon
            return item
        }
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Wow, not one reply yet, but i'm still working on it.  A lot tougher than i thought

Answer (score 0):

Change the showPosition function to the following. I also changed the variable ID long to getlon as long is a reserved word, also change lat to getlat.  3 days of perseverance

```
function showPosition(position) {

document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;

lon=document.getElementById("getlon").value;
lat=document.getElementById("getlat").value;

}
```